# RXJS Observables - http call for each index value and merge result

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I do a http call to get an Array with objs. And now I want to call for each objs that return me an **ID** another http call. After all I want to have **one** observable result.

So far I managed to get for each index a http call. The problem instead of one result I got multiple.

```
getStats(tag: string) {
    return this.service.getClanByClanTag(tag)
        .map(clan => {
            return clan.memberList; //the arr that return the ID's
        })
        .switchMap((member: PlayerByMemberListType[]) => {
            return member; // singleObj of the arr
        })
        .concatMap((singleMember) => {
            return this.service.getPlayerData(singleMember.tag).map(player => {
                //push data to the new arr which should return only one time
                this.newArr.push({
                    tag: singleMember.tag,
                    name: singleMember.name,
                    warStars: player.warStars,
                    trophiesNightBase: singleMember.versusTrophies
                });
                return this.newArr;
            });
        });
}
```

This is what the console prints out after subscribing to it:

```
Array [ {…} ]
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
...
```

I know I need some kind of `Observable.forkJoin` but I don't know how integrate it in the code.

Comment: Try using another `concatMap ` instead of map

Comment: with another concatMap i get almost 2500 objs as a result instead of an arr of 49 Objs :'D

Comment: did you use it on the first map `(.map(clan => { ....)`?

Comment: see [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
this.service.getClanByClanTag(tag)
    .mergeMap(clan => clan.memberList)
    .mergeMap(
        member => this.service.getPlayerData(member.tag), // supposedly this returns an observable
        (member, player) => ({ 
            tag: member.tag,
            name: member.name,
            warStars: player.warStars,
            trophiesNightBase: member.versusTrophies
        })
    )
    .toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want to achieve is this.

1. Get the clan info
2. Using clan info from step 1, get the `memberList` in the clan
3. For each member inside the `memberList`, get the players

You will need to think of a way to preserve the info at `step2` when before `switchMap` in `step3`. Usually we will use a `Subject`, but in the case if you do not want to, simply `map` the `Observable` to preserve the data:

```
getStats(tag: string) {
    return this.service.getClanByClanTag(tag)
        .map(clan => {
            return clan.memberList; //the arr that return the ID's
        })
        .switchMap((memberList: PlayerByMemberListType[]) => {
            //note that the following map is a function of javascript array, not Observable
            //it returns an array
            let arrayOfObservables = memberList.map(singleMember => {
                this.service.getPlayerData(singleMember.tag)
                //map the data so as to preserve the data of singleMember 
                //by creating a new object, using Object.assign
                    .map(playerData => {
                        return Object.assign({memberData: singleMember}, playerData,)
                    });
            })
            return Observable.forkJoin(arrayOfObservables);
        })
        .map(players => {
            //players is an array of Object that is the format of {memberData:singleMember, playerData:player)
            //perform Object destructuring method
            return players.map(({memberData,playerData}) => {
                return {
                    tag: memberData.tag,
                    name: memberData.name,
                    warStars: playerData.warStars,
                    trophiesNightBase: memberData.versusTrophies
                }
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed description of your approach, but smthng doesnt work out here, i get an error ' You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.' The arrayOfObservables prints me out: `Array(49) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, … ]`